# Wordpress - check if loop contains posts with attachments?

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress I'm trying to enqueue a script for a jQuery gallery only for posts that got attachments.

I got this simple function that works for single posts:

```
function gotImages()
{
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );
    return ( !empty($attachments) ? true : false );
}
```

When I call gotImages() in functions.php it returns true for a single post with attachments but false for the home page with several posts if the first post doesn't have attachments.

How can I modify this so it works for more than one post i.e. on the home page where I'm displaying 10 posts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked out a rough working solution. It's probably not the final version but here's my solution for anyone who might be interested.

```
function gotImages()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $posts = $wp_query->posts;

    if ( empty( $posts ) )
    return $posts;

    $searchImages = '~<img [^>]* />~';

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $content = $post->post_content;
        preg_match_all( $searchImages, $content, $countImages );
        $images += count($countImages[0]);
    }
    return ( $images >= 1 ? true : false );
}
```

This function if put in functions.php will read through the content of the current loop and scan it for `<IMG>` tags. If one or more tags are found it returns true otherwise false.

Now I can use this to conditionally enqueue scripts or stylesheets depending on if a post got any images.

For example like this:

```
if( !is_admin() && gotImages() == true ) :
    wp_register_script('fancybox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/libs/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
    wp_register_script('fancybox.init', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/init/lightbox.init', array('fancybox'), false, true);

    wp_enqueue_script('fancybox');
    wp_enqueue_script('fancybox.init');
endif;
```

I'm not sure yet how 'expensive' this function is but the site I'm working on it quite small so for now it's not a big deal of it adds a few ms to the process time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the loop on the homepage when you're displaying each of the ten posts, then calling it as is should produce the desired result. Whether it will work on multiple posts depends on the css selectors that you're using to run the slideshow. If you're using a CSS id, then your HTML will be invalid because you'll have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: It seems to just check the first post in the loop though. I need to work out how to loop through the rest if there are more than 1. The return from the function just decides if Wordpress should enqueue the javascript or not so got nothing to do with classes or ID's yet.

Comment: @Johannes can you post your php for your homepage?

Comment: Not at my computer right now but it's the default Twentyeleven theme. Btw I'm calling the function in functions.php so it's outside the loop.

Comment: You can define the function in your functions.php, but you should call if within the loop. So while you're in the loop, `if(gotImages()) { //do your stuff here }`

Comment: That's the thing I don't need it in the loop. I need to be able to call it outside the loop, in functions.php to be to contionally enqueue a script.

Comment: well if you're displaying ten posts, you have to be using a loop, a `while`, or a `foreach()` somewhere, right? Wherever that is, you could include the `if(gotImages()) { wp_enqueue_script(); }` But there shouldn't be a reason to call the same javascript over and over again. I think a better way to do it would be to enqueue the script once, and make your jQuery statement something like `jQuery("div.slidesWrap img").slidesMethod();`. In your function, return the images instead of a true-false statement `if(gotImages()) { foreach($images as $image) { // echo slide } }`